# Python: sum matching columns

Tags: python, csv

Input File is

```
10/14/2017 21:02  11/04/2017      134  15  
10/14/2017 21:02  11/04/2017      134  15  
10/14/2017 21:02  11/04/2017      134  15   
10/13/2017 20:58  11/03/2017      132  10  
10/13/2017 20:58  11/03/2017      132  10   
10/13/2017 20:58  11/03/2017      132  10  
10/13/2017 20:58  11/03/2017      132  10
```

I want the output as the sum of values in column 5 for matching values in column 1.

```
10/14/2017   45          //(ie. 15+15+15)   
10/13/2017   40          //(ie. 10+10+10+10)
```

Can someone help me with the Python code?

Comment: Using pandas...?

Comment: Its Solaris server I dont have pandas , I want to use csv

Comment: Please show what have you done so far and what went wrong. That will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` from `collections`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

temp = defaultdict(int)

with open("testfile.csv", 'r') as infile:

    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split()
        temp[fields[0]] += int(fields[-1])

print(temp)

# defaultdict(int, {'10/13/2017': 40, '10/14/2017': 45})
```

Comment: This works i got the output in this form defaultdict(int, {'10/13/2017': 40, '10/14/2017': 45})

Comment: Thanks stamaimer

Answer (score 1):

A good way to approach a problem like this is to try breaking it down into subproblems and solve each one separately. A breakdown for this problem might be:

1. How do I extract the contents of each line in my input file? Think about what separates each column.
2. How do I store a running total of column 5 for each value in column 0? You'll want some kind of data structure, ideally one that would let you do a quick lookup of totals for column 0 values.
3. How do I write out these totals and column 0 value to my output file when I'm done?

I would encourage you to continue solving the problem on your own before looking for someone to give you the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = """10/14/2017 21:02  11/04/2017      134  15
10/14/2017 21:02  11/04/2017      134  15
10/14/2017 21:02  11/04/2017      134  15
10/13/2017 20:58  11/03/2017      132  10
10/13/2017 20:58  11/03/2017      132  10
10/13/2017 20:58  11/03/2017      132  10
10/13/2017 20:58  11/03/2017      132  10
"""

result = {}

for line in data.splitlines():
    key = line.split(' ')[0]
    value = line.split(' ')[11]
    if result.get(key):
        result[key] = result[key] + int(value)
    else:
        result[key] = int(value)
print(result)
```

Comment: Using `-1` is so much better as shown by @stamaimer.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the dates in column 1 are sequential, you could read the CSV line by line, and if the date is the same as the previous date, add column 5 from that line to keep a running total. If the date is different then output the total, and restart the total from zero for the next date.